# Compare the mapping table and then change with the database headers(row 1)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

How do I compare a mapping table  (values  in different cells) in excel and map the value of that header to my main database.

Main Database:
[image: Main Database]

Mapping Table:
[image: this is the making table to which the headers (tanu, sweet, etc are the file names and the first row is the names in the database]

Tanu's Sheet:

[image]

It should map the headers(wgt, ht, bmi, etc)  of the file (tanu, sweety, Raju)  and compare it with main database and replace it with the headers of main database

```
 The code written so far
 Sub SelectColumn()
 Dim xColIndex As Integer
 Dim xRowIndex As Integer
   xIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
    xRowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 
     xIndex).End(xlUp).Row
     Range(Cells(2, xIndex), Cells(xRowIndex, xIndex)).Select
   End Sub
```

Can't get through

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are attempting to do, what do you mean by "map the value of that header to my main database"?

Comment: There is a mapping table in the image,  and the headers mismatch to my database, I just want it replaced by the headers of my database from column 1 of the picture @Xabier thanks

Comment: Where is your database and what does it look like? Do you mean that your database is simply another Worksheet in the same Workbook and you just want to replace the headers with the correct ones from your mapping table?

Comment: @Xabier, yes. My database is in a different sheet in same workbook and the headers of my main database is in row 1(height, weight, bmi). The other headers are (tanu, sweety, Raju) are my files with such headers (wgt, hit, etc) I just need to replace the headers in the files of tanu, Raju, sweety with my main dB headers. Sorry for being vague

Comment: use a dictionary: your keys will be the source field names and your items will be the name of the filed in the database so for example to map weight correctly you should insert these elements in the dictionary: `key=wg, item=weight` and `key=wgt item=weight` and `key=weight, item=weight`

Comment: How do I exclusively specify it? Could you please help me out since I'm an Ameture coder and also in some **files there is a column "wgt" which actually means "weight transfer"** in my main database. Can't really use a dictionary to specify just one value @Ibo

Comment: You need to have unique values for mapping. If wgt means weight in one source and means another thing in another sheet, there is no way that you can 100% programmatically automate this. You need to do some prep work and change the values manually

Comment: it still gives me a subscript out of range exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will check your mapping table and replace headers in each of their Sheets for each workbook tanu, sweety and etc, (it will look for the headers in the range A1:Z1000, change this if you need it to be a bigger range):

```
Sub foo3()
Dim Wbook As Workbook
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
LastCol = wb.Sheets("LMal").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Check how many columns in the Mapping Table
LastRow = wb.Sheets("LMal").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Check how many rows in the Mapping Table
For i = 2 To LastCol
    Filename = "C:\Users\tanu\Desktop\" & wb.Sheets("LMal").Cells(1, i) & ".xlsx" ' Get the Sheet name such as tanu, sweety, etc
    Set Wbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
        For x = 2 To LastRow ' loop through rows
        Search = wb.Sheets("LMal").Cells(x, i).Value
        On Error Resume Next
            For Each wSheet In Wbook.Worksheets
                Set strGotIt = wSheet.Cells.Find(What:=Search, After:=wSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
                If strGotIt <> vbNullString Then
                   wSheet.Cells(strGotIt.Row, strGotIt.Column).Value = wb.Sheets("LMal").Cells(x, 1).Value 'replace the value in tanu's sheet
                   On Error GoTo 0
                End If

            Next
           On Error GoTo 0
        Next x

Wbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. But it gives me an out of range error in  "Set FoundColumnNumber = Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:=Search, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'find the value in tanu's sheet" **could you help me out here**

Comment: Are the headers on say Tanu's Sheet somewhere in between A1 and Z1? If you could add a link to a sample spreadsheet here I will be able to have a better look at it? As the way it is, it is working for me with my test spreadsheet.

Comment: I uploaded the picture. But, the bmi seems to be missing from there and should not be included in the mapping table. I think that might create a problem

Comment: Uploaded it as Tanu's file

Comment: Are the header's always on row number 8 for all the sheets, for tanu, sweety, etc?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. They are on different lines always

Comment: @tanu, would you be able to upload the spreadsheet to something like Dropbox or Google Drive and comment the link here so I could have a look at it? It does the job for me, so I'm guessing there is something else at play here...

Comment: I hope I'm not doing anything that major of a mistake and also i'm an ameature

Comment: It could be something as simple as you didn't change the sheet name from Sheets("MappingTable") to whatever your sheet is actually called? But if you want this done asap, then you could send the a sample spreadsheet and I can make it work?

Comment: Will send it to you

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1UJHwy810IRTUTNC02q0oeTFlFLEOgezU

Comment: I thought you meant that tanu, sweety and raju were sheets within your main spreadsheet, are they actually separate files by themselves? If so are they saved in a specific folder? And are they named as tanu.xlsx, sweety.xlsx? Also are the headers for each file found in Sheet1?

Comment: Yes. they are in a folder where I store them in and they are sweety.xlsx

Comment: Which worksheet are you looking for the header's then? Are they all different? or are they all on Sheet1?

Comment: Tanu has two worksheets with same header but different data in each sheet. I need to map the headers in my main database by the mapping table and copt the value

Comment: Xabier could it be possible?

Comment: @tanu, I have now tried and tested this, please change the path of the files to whatever it may be and it should now work as expected.

Comment: @tanu if this code has helped you, could you mark my response as an answer?